# What to return when a route/url is found but not the resource behind it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When a route customer/1 exists but the resource/entity behind the customer search does not exist,

Should I return a 404? I mean the route exists...

or should I return a

204 (No content) because I could not find a customer and the result is empty.

**Microsoft sample:**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get (int id)
{
    Product product = _repository.Get (id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound(); // Returns a NotFoundResult
    }
    return Ok(product);  // Returns an OkNegotiatedContentResult
}
```

In my opinion a NotFound() => 404 is not correct here?!

**CLARIFICATION/IMPROVEMENT** of my question.

I need to distinguish between a

1) route: customer/1 => route does not exist

*( I would return here 404, but this is anyway handled by the framework...)*

2) route: customer/1 => exists but the resource/entity in database NOT

*( I would return here a 404)*

3) route: customersSearch/searchterm => the resource/entity in database is not found

*( I would return a 204 )*

Would you please be that kind and correct your answer to this more clear question please?

Comment: I'd go with a 204, the 5XX codes are for actual problems (like the underlying resource is not available). If there really is nothing to return, then return 204.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General REST guidelines state that in this instance you should return a 404. You have asked for a specific resource that doesn't exist. As if you had requested a physical document from a website.

At all my work places that has been the pattern and issued by the enterprise architecture teams :)

A word of advice though... have some form of logging for this scenario so you can detect a "logical" 404 (in this scenario) versus a true no resource / handler / script mapping was available to service the request! At least to identify issues at deploy time :)

Comment: 2xx are "here's your data", 4xx are "client did bad things", 5xx are "server did bad things."  Client requested data that doesn't exist, so 404 seems like the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

Its a design question but I agree with you that 404 is probably not the appropriate status code here since 4xx means client error. I would pick something from 2xx(204 is indeed a good choice here) or 5xx. For your reference, here's RFC for http status codes:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Based on your update, 204 is an acceptable return code.

Comment: The 500 range are reserved for server errors. This is not a server error, the client has requested a resource that doesn't exist. When you request a file or physical resource from a website that doesn't exist does that result in a 5xx error? No, 404!

Comment: Agreed but 501 can be a valid response here as well, from RFC  10.5.2 501: Not Implemented

The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request. This is the appropriate response when the server does not recognize the request method and is not capable of supporting it for any resource.

Comment: @Spencer But... a physical resource like a file means the route/url was wrong. And thats the problem I see. My Resource is found (url exists) but the search returns nothing. Sorry I guess my question was not that clear as it could be I will improve my question again.

Comment: I disagree, again this is not a server eror. 501 - Not Implemented. Doesn't describe the state of the request. In this scenario the functionality **is implemented**, just the resource you requested does not exist. As a consumer of this API you would think the server is in an error state.

Comment: @Elisabeth no the route is not wrong... it was processed and service. The resource requested was not found. There's a difference between routes and resources.

Comment: Reading the question, server is in fact incomplete state (When a route customer/1 exists but the resource/entity behind the customer search DOES NOT EXISTS) - I do not see any issue returning 501. But end of the day, it's a design choice - I have seen enterprise API returning all sorts of status code (even 200 for ALL calls!).

Comment: I updated my question!  and about your 200 for aLL calls, I work in such a big company  and am about to change all that...

Comment: @Elisabeth I would agree with your changes to your original question. For a query / search URI if the search executed without exception and didn't return any results a 204 would be suitable here :)

Comment: Fast forward 5 years, I would prefer to use 404 for coding simplicity. Returning 204 makes sense when using standard MVC with views. However, when dealing with REST and JSON, front end developers would have to write extra handler code for 204 as null result from controller does not pass through JSON formatter. This forces front-end coders to format 204 results themselves. It would be easier to catch a 404 and handle it that way.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a custom HTTP Reason Phrase to differentiate that the 404 was due to a resource not being found as opposed to a malformed URL resulting in an incorrect Route. The 404 is still the correct response code to use under all 3 scenarios, yet if you are trying to make development time easier by differentiating the reasons, then use a different reason phrase.

e.g.

1. Incorrect route returns default `404 Not Found`
2. Correct route, but no resource with that ID found `404 Customer Not Found`
3. Correct route, but no resources found that match the search criteria `404 No Customers Found`

I interpret 204 as different from the above comments in that the [204 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) states (emphasis mine):

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not **need** to return an entity-body

in this scenario, the api did need to return an entity-body, it simply wasn't able to because the requested information wasn't available. Hence it was *Not Found*

Example of how to return a custom reason phrase in Web API.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get (int id)
{
    Product product = _repository.Get (id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "");
        response.ReasonPhrase = "Product Not Found";
        return response;
    }
    return Ok(product);  // Returns an OkNegotiatedContentResult
}
```