# How to differentiate whether the server hosting a resource(on url) is down or if the resource doesn't exist when a HttpStatus code of 404 is returned

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, spring-rest

Using Spring's RestTemplate.exchange(url, HTTP.GET,String.class) signature to access a resource using a URL and GET Http method, how can we differentiate whether the server hosting the resource(represented by url) is down or if the server couldn't find the resource  and hence it returned the HttpStatus code of 404.

I would like to base by retry mechanism on this difference, I would not look to retry if the resource doesn't exist. But I would retry after a configurable back-off time period in hope the server gets up if the server is down.

I have referred to HTTPStatus class in spring source and found reference to a url - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5

*6.5.4.  404 Not Found
The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
willing to disclose that one exists.  A 404 status code does not
indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
permanent; the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the
origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
the condition is likely to be permanent.
A 404 response is cacheable by default; i.e., unless otherwise
indicated by the method definition or explicit cache controls (see
Section 4.2.2 of [RFC7234]).*

I have read through : ([Is 404 the right return code for a resource that currently doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971221/is-404-the-right-return-code-for-a-resource-that-currently-doesnt-exist)) and ([What to return when a route/url is found but not the resource behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840365/what-to-return-when-a-route-url-is-found-but-not-the-resource-behind-it)). But I couldn't find an article to help me differentiate the two scenarios.

Handling the HttpClientErrorException and looking at the ResponseBody field could be a possible solution, but I felt it might not be correct way to do it.

Comment: There should be something in the response headers

Comment: You are correct sir, so is Micheal Peacock.

The server being down is treated as an I/O error on the client side and a ResourceAccessException is being thrown by RestTemplate.

ResourceAccessException - for Server being down.
HttpStatusCodeException - when the server is up and a status code is returned. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP 404 status is a valid response that can only be returned by a running server when it cannot find the resource being requested. If the server is down, however, your connection would be refused.

Answer (score 0):

The server being down is treated as an I/O error on the client side and a ResourceAccessException is being thrown by RestTemplate.

ResourceAccessException - for Server being down.

HttpStatusCodeException - when the server is up and a status code is returned(4xx -series throws the subclass exception HttpClientErrorException, 5xx-series throws the subclass exception HttpServerErrorException).